# Problem with odd/even child elements in nth-child

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have a web site like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="article_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section">
    <!--<h1>header</h1>-->
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
        <div>
            paragraph
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is CSS:

```
div.section
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div.section div:nth-child(even)
{
    color: Green;
}
div.section div:nth-child(odd)
{
    color: Red;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

This is OK because I get red for odd div and green for even in **each** section.
But when I add header at the begginig of first section (commented code in sample) I get this:

[image: result2]

I don't want that. I want the to have like before, but just with a header in first section. So at first header and then red paragraph.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/JSWHH/)

```
div.section
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div.section div:nth-of-type(even)
{
    color: Green;
}
div.section div:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works!
However, I'm not sure why would anyone use `nth-child` if it doesn't look at type. What's the use of it?

Comment: @CichyK24: The classic use case is [zebra-striping](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/zebra-striping-tables-with-css3/) the rows of a table or list.

Comment: @CichyK24: Yes, that would work also work with `nth-of-type`, but it's more specific than you need. There are situations when you simply have to use one over the other. That alone means both pseudo-classes are useful. If you *really* want me to, I'll make a demo showing a situation where `nth-child` does what I want where `nth-of-type` doesn't :)

Comment: OK, I get it. You don't have to make a demo ;-)

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Love it :) so much

Answer (score 4):

```
div > :nth-child(3)     the third child of a div element
div > :nth-child(even)  every even child of a div element
div > :nth-child(odd)   every odd child of a div element
div > :nth-child(3n)    every third child of a div element
```