# Alternate display of posts on my website

Tags: html, css

I have a blog/website something like this and I'm trying to make each post display in alternate order. The image of the first post displays on the right and the second post image displays on the left...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="section">
    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture1.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
      <h2>Post Title 1</h2>
      <p>post contents post contents</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture2.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
      <h2>Post Title 2</h2>
      <p>post contents post contents</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture3.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
      <h2>Post Title 3</h2>
      <p>post contents post contents</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture4.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
      <h2>Post Title 4</h2>
      <p>post contents post contents</p>
    </article>  
</div> <!-- /.section -->

</body>
</html>
```

I'm aware about the CSS nth-child and nth-of-type selectors but still newbie on how to properly use it.

I have this sample CSS code that I modeled from the answer here: [Problem with odd/even child elements in nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195367/problem-with-odd-even-child-elements-in-nth-child) but I can't make it properly style the tags inside the article element.

```
div.section article img:nth-of-type(odd) {
    float: right;
}

div.section article img:nth-of-type(even) {
    float: left;
}
```

I searched for some model design and I found this which is something similar to my site.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach nth of type to the article

```
div.section article:nth-of-type(odd) img {
    float: right;
}

div.section article:nth-of-type(even) img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I think one of them should be `float: left;`

Comment: No, I meant in your answer as well. Should it not be `float:left` for even?

Comment: Thank you ! Your solution helps me to fix my problem. Though the answer is not complete as per my problem but managed it to model your answer and solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this sample ? 
https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/k4gvdqhg/

style code

```
   .section{width:300px;}
div.section article:nth-of-type(odd) img {
    float: left;
}

div.section article:nth-of-type(even) img {
    float: right;
}

#w_odd {
    float: left;
}

#w_even {
    float: right; 
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="section">
    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture1.jpg" width="100" alt="1" height="100" /></a>    
    <div id="w_odd">  <h2>Post Title 1</h2>
    <p>post contents post contents</p> </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture2.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
  <div id="w_even"> 
   <h2>Post Title 2</h2>
      <p>post contents post contents</p>
      </div> 
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture3.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
   <div id="w_odd">    <h2>Post Title 3</h2>
   <p>post contents post contents</p> </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <a href="#"><img src="/img/picture4.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a>    
   <div id="w_even">     <h2>Post Title 4</h2>
   <p>post contents post contents</p> </div>
    </article>  
</div> <!-- /.section -->
```